# how to separate multiple input from the same div and get it in the parent component accordingly

Tags: javascript, user-input, react-props, setstate

I have a input (Inputu) function like so :

```
cexport default ({ onChange, value1, value2, value3, name }: any) => {
  return (
  <div name={name}>
      <form >
        <div>
          <label> </label>
          <input value={value1} onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label></label>
          <select onChange={onChange} value = {value2}>
            <option>text</option>        
          </select>
        </div>
        <div >
          <label></label>
          <select value={value3} onChange={onChange}>
            <option>text</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

this is a dynamic function that added in the app component as the user pressing a button like so:

```
    class App extends Component {
       constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          clikctime: 0,
          q1: []
         
        };
      }
    
     onChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
        const value1= currentTarget.value.value1;
        const value2 = currentTarget.value.value2;
        const value3 = currentTarget.value.value3;
        const index = this.state.clikctime;
        let q1 = [...this.state.q1];
    
        q3[index - 1] = [value1,value2 ,value3];
    
        this.setState({ q1 });
      
       };
     
        renderInputs = ({ value1, value2, value3 }, idx) => {
        const name = this.state.clikctime;
        
        return (
          <Inputu key={idx} value1={value1} value2={value2} value3={value3} name={name} onChange= 
           {this.onChangeu} />
        );
      };


  addInputs = () => {
    const newclick = this.state.clikctime;
    const nw = newclick + 1;
    this.setState({ clikctime: nw });
    this.setState({ q1: this.state.q1.concat(nw) });
  };

render() {
    return (
   
        <div>
          <button 

            onClick={this.addInputs}> 
             click on me to add question ! 
    
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.q1.map(this.renderInputs)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I couldn't manage to separate the value, also how can I add the state as list\dic so the input would be associated with name\id (regardless of how many times the user klicked the button and add input)

In the end I would like to get somting like that:

```
q1: {name1:[value1 ,value2, value3], name2:[value1 ,value2, value3]....}
```

Thanks for trying to help